# При открытии страницы отправляется постбэк один раз

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать код, по которому при открытие страницы (страницы спасибо после заказа) отправлялся постбэк (открывалась определенная ссылка, но её не видели) один раз. На данный момент у меняя реализовано следующим образом:

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://постбэк.ру" />
```

Но в данном случае, если клиент обновляет страницу спасибо код срабатывает еще раз, накидывая неправильную стату. Как можно исправить?

Comment: <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://постбэк.ру" />

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Когда клиент оставляет заказ, открывается страница (с номером заказа, словами благодарности и т.д.), в этой странице прописан код: <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="постбэк.ру" /> , который отправляет мне в телеграмм инфу о заказе, но если обновить страницу , то код отрабатывает повторно. Необходимо чтобы код срабатывал один раз и при обновлении страницы более не срабатывал